# MYSQL query by example(QBE)

Tags: mysql, database, regex, query-by-example

I really don't understand this

QBE

means.. I have searched but i unable to understand this term ..

My client need to

> generate report using QBE

as my knowledge this is **REGEXP** search but not clear,

can anyone have the better example to understand this.. 
Please share with me Thanks !

Comment: AFAIK QBE is the access tool that let people who don't know nothing about sql to create queries with drag and drop. http://www.cwnresearch.com/resources/databases/access/tutorials/access2000/CreatingQBEQueries/CreatingQBEQueries.html

Answer (score 2):

Query by example(QBE) is simple way of writing DB queries in more flexible ways.

e.g. I can search a string "doc" in my DB table by specifying doc.. in my search box.
Then it will search all string start with "doc".

In your case report page should have some kind of filters. From where you can specify your inputs. Depending upon values filled, appropriate query will be formed and fired over MySQL.

Please remember that QBE is just a layer above query model.

Thanks,
Rajendra.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Access, you can create queries using SQL or QBE.  QBE looks like a spreadsheet with ~5 rows (sort of).  When you drag a table column to the sheet, it will be added as a column.  You use the rows to specify filtering (the WHERE clause).  Expressions going across in the same row are ANDED together, expressions on different rows are ORed together.

So you might have this...

name      | age  | age
          |      |
= 'Smith' | > 10 | < 20
          |

would yield...
"SELECT name, age FROM  WHERE name = 'Smith' AND age > 10 AND age < 20